# Git less shows an error message and bad output. How can I fix it?

Tags: git, less

After installing delta and some configuration around it, Git less (the default pager) seems to have gotten screwed up.  For example, if I do a `git log`, the results look like this:

```
>git log
-" must be followed by 1 or 2 chars
Press RETURN to continue
```

The logs that follow have strange formatting with a bunch of "ESC" and other oddities:

```
ESC[33mcommit fcb45[...]
```

I've found the actual error message in less here:

https://github.com/gdamore/less-fork/blob/master/optfunc.c#L489

But how do I fix this?

I've tried:

1. Reinstalling Git.
2. Uninstalling Git, deleting `C:\Program Files\Git`, and then reinstalling.
3. Deleting the Delta pager and removing it from PATH.

It would make sense to me to reinstall Less, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more searching around, I discovered that while trying to get Delta to work with `git add -p`, I created this environment variable:

[image: LESS environment variable]

When I deleted this and restarted my Windows command prompt, the problem went away.